# Push-pull mechanism

Tags: push-pull, movement

I'm new here and I'm sorry if this question is inappropriate.
I'm trying to build refreshable braille display that will be placed inside of a desk, so I have a lot of vertical space. To build display I need some kind of mechanism that will pull and push letters, I've used push-pull electro magnets, but they are too big, so what can I use instead of them to move parts.

Comment: https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/open-source-braille-display#/. http://www.utopiamechanicus.com/article/open-source-hardware-braille-display/.

Comment: [Piezoelectric "squiggle" motors](https://www.newscaletech.com/resources/technology/squiggle-micro-motor-technology/) produce linear motion, are tiny and self-locking. I don't know how expensive they are in quantity, however.